# Middleware Ordering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a new .NET Core 3.1 app and am struggling with the concept of Middleware. From reading around, it seems the order of including different middlewares is important. I currently have several problems which I can't seem to solve:

1. I never see the developer error page, and have to check the event log to see what's happened if there's an error. I just get the blank "error 500" etc pages from Chrome. The custom error pages also never display when there's a 500/400.
2. The app always tries to redirect me to */Account/Login* despite changing this in the cookie settings.
3. *User.IsAuthenticated* returns false when the *CheckPermissionsAction* call is made in Elmah, so I can't access Elmah. The *User.IsInRole* call works for from controllers though.

This is how I'm bootstrapping the app. It feels like something is overriding the settings:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2));

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/error/denied");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/log-off");
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        })
        .AddUserStore<UserStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyApp");
            options.CheckPermissionAction = (context)=>{
                return context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.User.IsInRole(RoleHelper.SuperAdmin);
            };
            options.Path = "/elmah";
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAppConfiguration, AppConfiguration>(e => Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig")
           .Get<AppConfiguration>());

        OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<DbHelper>(services, Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // wire up using autofac specific APIs here
        builder.Register(context => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<User, MyDetailsViewModel>();
        })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterModule(new RegistrationModule()); // separate assembly, wires up autofac registrations
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            //This resolves a new context that can be used later.
            var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            var config = context.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>();
            return config.CreateMapper(context.Resolve);
        })
        .As<IMapper>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // debugger shows this section is called, but I never see the error page.
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseRouteDebugger();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseElmah();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
        };
        app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Guest}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseStatusCodePages(async ctx =>
        {
            //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
            string originalPath = ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
            switch (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 401:
                    //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
                    ctx.HttpContext.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                    ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/error/denied";
                    break;
                case 412:
                    ctx.HttpContext.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                    ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/error/expired-account";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    ctx.HttpContext.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                    ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/error/not-found";
                    break;
                case 500:
                    ctx.HttpContext.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                    ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/error/not-found";
                    break;
            }
        });
        DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new[]
            {
                 Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyApp.Domain.Model.Note)),
                 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

In regards to the order of your middleware, there is a problem with it.

There is a section in the Microsoft docs dedicated to the [order of middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order), I suggest reading it.

As for your middleware, the correct order would be:

```cs
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStatusCodePages(async ctx =>
        {
            // Omitted for brevity.
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            // Omitted for brevity.
        };
        app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        // If the app uses session state, call Session Middleware after Cookie
        // Policy Middleware and before MVC Middleware.
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseElmah(); // Not sure about this one. I don't know what it's supposed to do?

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            // Omitted for brevity.
        });

        DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new[]
        {
            // Omitted for brevity.
        });
```

Comment: That page is really useful, thanks. The issue of accessing elmah is now resolved but the authentication path is still the default and the custom error pages aren't shown. Neither is the developer error page. From what I can tell, the services don't need to be initialized in a specific order, only the middlware?

Comment: Correct. Services are called upon as they are needed (through the dependency injection container) and middleware runs for every request, it's the pipeline through which everything flows.

Comment: @Echilon I guess it's not hitting the developer exception page middleware because you are handling it with UseStatusCodePages. Try commenting the UseStatusCodePages and see if the developer exception middleware takes over.

Comment: The link provided is for .NET Core 3.1. For .NET Core 6 use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order (Or just change the version in the dropdown)

Comment: Check, updating it with the new link. Thanks Dodger.